# Laravel - Tokenmissmatchexception with Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-4, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js for uploading images to my site, but Laravel always reports TokenMismatchException although I'm using `Form::open()` in form, which automatically adds `_token`.

This is my code:

```
{{ Form::open(["class" => "dropzone", "id" => "imgUpload", "action" => "UploadsController@uploadImage"]) }}
    <div class="fallback">
        {{ Form::submit() }}
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

js

```
Dropzone.options.imgUpload = {
        paramName: "file",
        dictDefaultMessage: "Pošalji sliku",
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
        uploadprogress: function(progress, bytesSent){
            console.log(progress);
   }
};
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you setting up any filters in the `UploadsController` constructor?  ie... `$this->beforeFilter()`

Comment: I added global protection in routes: Route::when('*', 'csrf', array('post', 'put', 'delete'));

Answer (score 1):

It would appear as though Dropzone does not include the token when posting via AJAX.  You can use something like this to make it do so....

```
Dropzone.options.imgUpload = {
    paramName: "file",
    dictDefaultMessage: "Pošalji sliku",
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
    uploadprogress: function(progress, bytesSent) {
        console.log(progress);
    },
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
            // Pass token. You can use the same method to pass any other values as well such as a id to associate the image with for example.
            formData.append("_token", $('[name=_token']).val()); // Laravel expect the token post value to be named _token by default
        }
};
```

I found that snippet here... http://laravel.io/forum/04-17-2014-tokenmismatchexception-with-dropzonejs

It also looks like there are some problems with tokens and forms being submitted via AJAX.  In that case, you will want to include the additional header when initializing dropzone.

```
Dropzone.options.imgUpload = {
    paramName: "file",
    dictDefaultMessage: "Pošalji sliku",
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
    headers: {
        "X-CSRF-Token": $('[name=_token').val())
    },
    uploadprogress: function(progress, bytesSent) {
        console.log(progress);
    }
};
```

And to utilize this, modify your CSRF filter in `filters.php` to check for that header if we are submitting via AJAX.

```
Route::filter('csrf', function() 
{
    $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') : Input::get('_token');

    if (Session::token() != $token) {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this before but it's the same. When I open FireBug, I can see that dropzone is sending _token, and when I include your code, then it's sending _token twice, so there must be another problem.

Comment: I just compared token in meta tag with token in dropzone ajax request, and they are completely the same, so what could be the problem.

Comment: I might have another idea, can you update your question though to include your CSRF filter?

Comment: Same thing, really really strange. After I removed csrf filter from filters.php then everything worked, but of course then my app was unprotected.

Comment: That is pretty strange.  See if in your filter, you can `var_dump(Session::token())` and see if it returns any value when inspecting with firebug.

Comment: I did and I get session with no problems, and it's the same as in meta tag where I stored session

Comment: I believe this is a problem with dropzone.js because I switched to this plugin: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html and everything is ok. Thanks for your help

Comment: Youre missing `]` after `_token`